# What do I do if I ask a question and it gets down voted before I can fix it?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question, and because the code I was talking about was both now useless, and quite extensive, I just explained what I was trying to do, but didn't show the code. I got a couple of "show code" comments, and it got voted down. I decided then to edit the question showing what I had found that might be a solution, but really didn't match the original question now. But now nobody is looking at my question, and it got voted down before I could even add the edits. Isn't there a way to change a question's votes after an edit?

Comment: Learn from it and do better the next time. That might sound blunt, but it's the best course of action for *your current situation*.

Comment: Some users do tend to revisit questions they downvoted later to see if they have been improved and if they need to change their vote.

Answer (score 5):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18685832/1488917) has received just one downvote from what I can see. That not enough to hide the question from the front page or to stop it from appearing after you make edits.

I would suggest being patient and letting people evaluate and answer the question as they come across it.

> Isn't there a way to change a question's votes after an edit?

No, there isn't. Users who previously cast the downvote may however come across it again and revert their votes.

Also, have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/). Keep these points in mind before posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  You can improve the post such that users coming across the post now are much less likely to downvote it, or may even upvote it, and if someone who downvoted earlier happens to look at it again they could reverse their vote, but there is no way to reset the votes just because you've edited the content.

This is the consequence of posting a problematic post; you can and should fix it, but the consequences of the original post don't go away entirely, which is why you should take care to post a quality question from the start, to the best of your ability.

Comment: Yes, I kind of assumed all that. My original question was hard to ask because the service I was trying to find a replacement for is no longer there, so the code is defunct. I think what upset me was saying I didn't research anything. I've been doing nothing but searching for an answer for this. I've never been very good at wording things. It catches up with me sometimes.

Comment: @TomP possibly its unfair to say you didn't do any research, a better wording would be "didnt **show** research effort"

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about SO is number of people who are willing to help others with their questions/problems. Unfortunately some people try to take advantage of that and expect the community to solve their problems without prior effort to solve it by themself. Besides making your question easier to understand, showing your code is also your prove that you showed some efforts  on that matter yourself.

You can't do anything about the down votes and based on that I agree with the comment of @Joachim Sauer  who said:

> Learn from it and do better the next time. That might sound blunt, but it's the best course of action for your current situation.

Don't take it personal - you're not the only one who did that mistake - I had to lear it the same way since I did the same mistake with my very first question too :)

Comment: After all that, while this was going on, I think I might have stumbled upon my own answer to the the question.